# PHP Using RegEx(preg match) to get substring of a string

Tags: regex, preg-match

Hi I'm trying to parse a sub string with php preg_match.

String input like :

```
25k8cp1gl6-Mein Herze  im Blut, BWV 199: Recitative: Ich  Wunden_SVD1329578_14691639_unified :CPN_trans:
```

Here I want to extract `Mein Herze  im Blut, BWV 199: Recitative: Ich  Wunden`

```
25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_SVD1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:
```

Here I want to extract `La Puesta Del Sol`

```
La Puesta Del Sol_SVD1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:
```

Here I want to extract `La Puesta Del Sol`

```
25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_MNA1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:
```

Here I want to extract `La Puesta Del Sol`

```
25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_IMC1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:
```

Here I want to extract `La Puesta Del Sol`

So basically I want to extract the string before `_SVD` or `_MNA` and `_IMC` excluding the first part of the string `25k8cp1gl6-`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [an expression](http://regex101.com/r/dY1xE7) for ya:

```
(?<=25k8cp1gl6-).*?(?=_(?:SVD|MNA|IMC))
```

**Explanation:**

`(?<=...)` is syntax for a lookahead, meaning we start by finding (but not including in our match) "25k8cp1gl6-".  Then we lazily match our entire string with `.*?`.  Finally, `(?=...)` is a lookahead syntax.  We look for "_" followed by "SVD", "MNA", or "IMC" (separated with `|` in the non-capturing group `(?:...)`).

**PHP:**

```
$strings = array(
    '25k8cp1gl6-Mein Herze  im Blut, BWV 199: Recitative: Ich  Wunden_SVD1329578_14691639_unified :CPN_trans:',
    '25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_SVD1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:',
    '25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_MNA1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:',
    '25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_IMC1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:',
);

foreach($strings as $string) {
    if(preg_match('/(?<=25k8cp1gl6-).*?(?=_(?:SVD|MNA|IMC))/', $string, $matches)) {
        $substring = reset($matches);
        var_dump($substring);
    }
}
```

---

Another option, which would use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), is [demoed here](http://regex101.com/r/oX0uR5):

```
^\w+-(.*?)_(?:SVD|MNA|IMC).*
```

**Explanation:**

This one matches the entire string, but captures the part we want to keep so that we can reference it in our replacement.  Also note that I began with `^\w+-` instead of `25k8cp1gl6-`.  This pretty much just looks for any number of "word characters" (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) followed by a hyphen at the beginning of the string.  If it needs to be "25k8cp1gl6-", you can replace this; I just wanted to show another option.

**PHP:**

```
$strings = array(
    '25k8cp1gl6-Mein Herze  im Blut, BWV 199: Recitative: Ich  Wunden_SVD1329578_14691639_unified :CPN_trans:',
    '25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_SVD1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:',
    '25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_MNA1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:',
    '25k8cp1gl6-La Puesta Del Sol_IMC1133599_12537702_unified :CPN_trans:',
);

foreach($strings as $string) {
    $substring = preg_replace('/^\w+-(.*?)_(?:SVD|MNA|IMC).*/', '$1', $string);
    var_dump($substring);
}
```

Comment: First part contains some Alphanumeric characters, so I changed it to (?<=[a-zA-Z0-9_]-)(.*?)(?=_(?:SVD|MNA|IMC)) It's working, Thanks a lot Sam!

Comment: No problem, I added a second alternative.  Also note that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is equivalent to `\w`.

Comment: It gives the required sub string correctly if the first part "25k8cp1gl6-" is present, but for my case first part is optional.

Comment: I completely missed that, check out: [`(?:\w+-)?\K.*?(?=_(?:SVD|MNA|IMC))`](http://regex101.com/r/lW4aX7)..I can update/explain if you need

Comment: This works great, how about extracting the SVD1133599_12537702 part or IMC1133599_12537702 or MNA1133599_12537702 or SVD1133599 part or IMC1133599 or MNA1133599. here please note that "_12537702" is optional

Comment: I have one version that works but that seems pretty complex, so asking as you write very beautifull regex.

Comment: Here is one expression that will match everything you want, with the stipulations you have, and capture the two parts into two different groups: [`(?:\w+-)?(.*?)_((?:SVD|MNA|IMC)\d+(?:_\d+)?)`](http://regex101.com/r/mN7sO0). You will then access these two groups in PHP with `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`.